# Redirect all urls with parameters from old domain to new except one url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite

In order to redirect all requests from old domain `https://old4.old3.old2.ua` to new domain `https://new4.new3.new2.ua` I implemented the following rules in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://new4.new3.new2.ua/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I also need to allow requests(with parameters) on old domain to the one following url

```
https://old4.old3.old2.ua/vacancies/rss
```

and do not redirect it to the new domain.

How to add this exception into the .htaccess rules?

**UPDATED**

I have the following `.htaccess` file for my website:

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/vacancies/rss [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://new4.new3.new2.ua/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Right now everything works as expected except one thing:

when I access following url: `http://old4.old3.old2.ua/vacancies/rss?rid=34` it redirects me to `http://old4.old3.old2.ua/vacancies/rss/?rid=34` with `/` between `rss` and `?rid` but the expected url in this case is the same url as originally requested - `http://old4.old3.old2.ua/vacancies/rss?rid=34`

My server configuration is the following - the website is running on Apache server behind Nginx proxy server.

**This is Nginx config:**

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name old4.old3.old2.ua;

charset utf-8;

gzip on;
client_max_body_size 100m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

root /srv/www/htdocs/old4.old3.old2.ua/;

location / {
if (-f /srv/www/htdocs/old4.old3.old2.ua/maintenance.enable) {
return 503;
}
auth_basic "Restricted zone"; 
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/bonus.passwd;

proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:81 /;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}

location ~^\/web\/images.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico) {
root /srv/www/htdocs/old4.old3.old2.ua/;
}

location ~* ^.+\.(htm|html|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|bz2|pdf|odt|txt|tar|bmp|rtf|js|swf|svg|mp4|mp3|ogg|flv)$ {
root /srv/www/htdocs/old4.old3.old2.ua/web;
}

error_page 503 @maintenance;
location @maintenance {
rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html break;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
root /srv/www/htdocs/;
} 


location ~ /\.ht {
deny all;
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/certbot/live/old4.old3.old2.ua/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/certbot/live/old4.old3.old2.ua/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/certbot/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot


}
```

**Apache config:**

```
<VirtualHost *:81>

ServerName old4.old3.old2.ua

DocumentRoot /srv/www/htdocs/old4.old3.old2.ua

# if not specified, the global error log is used
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/old4.old3.old2.ua-error_log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/old4.old3.old2.ua-access_log combined

# don't loose time with IP address lookups
HostnameLookups Off

# needed for named virtual hosts
UseCanonicalName Off

# configures the footer on server-generated documents
ServerSignature On

Include /etc/apache2/conf.d/php7.conf

DirectoryIndex index.php

<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/old4.old3.old2.ua">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
# Order allow,deny
# Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RewriteCond` directive to exclude the URI .

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/vacancies/rss [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://new4.new3.new2.ua/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now, the following url works fine:  `https://old4.old3.old2.ua/vacancies/rss/` but the url `https://old4.old3.old2.ua/vacancies/rss` still redirects to new site. How to apply this rule to url without the trailing slash?

Comment: @alexanoid This should work for the traling slash too. Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: @ starkeen please see my updated question. I tried to remove the cache.. but it didn't help